# jp2 crashes QGIS

Tags: qgis, jpeg-2000

I am trying to open a jp2 image in QGIS, running on an Ubuntu laptop. The file is only 144 mb, but when I attempt to open it my memory usage spikes (16gb) and then my entire swap partition fills up before QGIS crashes. [Here is a link to the image I am trying to open](http://files.hawaii.gov/dbedt/op/gis/data/Hawaii_Landsat_Mosaic_Bathymetric_Fill.zip). I am simply trying to use this image as a base layer for a map, and I have used this same image in ArcGIS in the past without a problem. Any help?

Edit: I am running QGIS v2.18.4 and Ubuntu 16.04.2. I also just tried a smaller jp2 file (16mb) from a different source and it loaded fine. When I run gdalinfo on the larger file I get:

```
$ gdalinfo ~/GIS/Hawaii/Hawaii_Landsat_Mosaic_Bathymetric_Fill/Hawaii_Landsat_Mosaic_Bathymetric_Fill.jp2
Driver: JP2OpenJPEG/JPEG-2000 driver based on OpenJPEG library
Files: /home/drl/GIS/Hawaii/Hawaii_Landsat_Mosaic_Bathymetric_Fill/Hawaii_Landsat_Mosaic_Bathymetric_Fill.jp2
       /home/drl/GIS/Hawaii/Hawaii_Landsat_Mosaic_Bathymetric_Fill/Hawaii_Landsat_Mosaic_Bathymetric_Fill.j2w
       /home/drl/GIS/Hawaii/Hawaii_Landsat_Mosaic_Bathymetric_Fill/Hawaii_Landsat_Mosaic_Bathymetric_Fill.jp2.aux.xml
Size is 56475, 37033
Coordinate System is:
PROJCS["NAD83 / UTM zone 4N",
    GEOGCS["NAD83",
        DATUM["North_American_Datum_1983",
            SPHEROID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.2572221010002,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7019"]],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6269"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4269"]],
    PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",-159],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","26904"]]
Origin = (309113.084949130425230,2497001.832684248685837)
Pixel Size = (12.499890535238945,-12.500000000000000)
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  309113.085, 2497001.833) (160d51'23.67"W, 22d34' 8.57"N)
Lower Left  (  309113.085, 2034089.333) (160d48'24.88"W, 18d23'17.66"N)
Upper Right ( 1015044.403, 2497001.833) (153d59'49.15"W, 22d30' 6.80"N)
Lower Right ( 1015044.403, 2034089.333) (154d 7'48.91"W, 18d20' 4.15"N)
Center      (  662078.744, 2265545.583) (157d26'45.35"W, 20d28'53.75"N)
Band 1 Block=1024x1024 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
  Description = Red
  Overviews: 28237x18516, 14118x9258, 7059x4629, 3529x2314, 1764x1157, 882x578, 441x289, 220x144
  Overviews: arbitrary
  Image Structure Metadata:
    COMPRESSION=JP2000
Band 2 Block=1024x1024 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
  Description = Green
  Overviews: 28237x18516, 14118x9258, 7059x4629, 3529x2314, 1764x1157, 882x578, 441x289, 220x144
  Overviews: arbitrary
  Image Structure Metadata:
    COMPRESSION=JP2000
Band 3 Block=1024x1024 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
  Description = Blue
  Overviews: 28237x18516, 14118x9258, 7059x4629, 3529x2314, 1764x1157, 882x578, 441x289, 220x144
  Overviews: arbitrary
  Image Structure Metadata:
    COMPRESSION=JP2000
```

Comment: Do any other jp2 files work? What version of QGIS are you running? Can you run gdalinfo on the jp2 file from the command line? What's the resolution of this jp2 file? (sorry, no time to download 144Mb right now, but you should include basic info about your data in the question).

Comment: I will edit post to provide more details

Comment: As gdalinfo reports the file that you have problems with has 56475x37033 pixels. What gdalinfo does not tell is that the image is compressed as one single tile and OpenJPEG library has a limitation that it must decompress the tile entirely before it can continue. ECWJP2 can utilize another tiling-like feature in JPEG2000 called "precincts" and therefore it does not have memory problems.

Comment: I just experienced the exact same problem. The JP2 was outputted from Esri, and all other JP2 files work fine on my Ubuntu system. Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: I reverted to an older version of QGIS and everything worked. Not a satisfying solution, I know...

Answer (score 2):

If you are using QGIS from an OSGeo4W Network Installer, you probably need to install the ECW support, which includes JP2:

[image]

Without this package, you won't be able to load any jp2 image (or maybe you will see a black image). I just installed it using the Advanced OSGeo4W Setup and it works by now:

[image]

Comment: I installed QGIS from the UbuntuGIS repository today and it appears to have included the JP2OpenJPEG JPEG-2000 driver.

Comment: As I added to my comment above I seem to be able to open other jp2 images, but this one maxes out 16 ram and 16 gb swap, which does not seem to make sense given the file size. Did opening this file use such large amounts of memory on your system?

Comment: It loaded instantly. I didn't realize you are working on Ubuntu and I'm unfamiliar with it, but there should be something similar also for it.